# What do these errors mean, and how do I fix them?

Tags: java, runtime-error

So Ive been trying to make a basic Video game, just to get an understanding of how they work. I already made a working model, but i tried to streamline it, and make it easier to modify/add components.

Here are the two classes in my program:

```
package KernelGame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class VGKernel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{

public static final Graphics g = null;
public static Rectangle screen;
static Ball[] ball = new Ball[5]; 
public static Rectangle bounds;  
public static JFrame frame; 
public static VGTimerTask vgTask; 

public static Rectangle player;
public static int move; 


  public VGKernel(){
    super();
    screen = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
    makeBalls();
    bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600); 
    frame = new JFrame("VGKernel");
    vgTask = new VGTimerTask();
    player = new Rectangle(0, 541, 30, 30);
    frame.addKeyListener(this);
    frame.requestFocus();
}

    public static void makeBalls(){

        ball[0] = new Ball(0, 0, 20, 20, true, true);
        ball[1] = new Ball(25, 25, 20, 20, true, true);
        ball[2] = new Ball(50, 50, 20, 20, true, true);
        ball[3] = new Ball(75, 75, 20, 20, true, true);
        ball[4] = new Ball(100, 100, 20, 20, true, true);
    }

  class VGTimerTask extends TimerTask{
    public void run(){
        Ball.moveBalls(Ball.ball[0]);
        Ball.moveBalls(Ball.ball[1]);
        Ball.moveBalls(Ball.ball[2]);
        Ball.moveBalls(Ball.ball[3]);
        Ball.moveBalls(Ball.ball[4]);
        checkCollisions();
        frame.repaint();

    }
  }


  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    bounds = g.getClipBounds();

    g.clearRect(screen.x, screen.y, screen.width, screen.height);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(Ball.ball[0].x, Ball.ball[0].y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(Ball.ball[1].x, Ball.ball[1].y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(Ball.ball[2].x, Ball.ball[2].y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(Ball.ball[3].x, Ball.ball[3].y, 20, 20);
    g.fillRect(Ball.ball[4].x, Ball.ball[4].y, 20, 20);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRoundRect(player.x, player.y, player.width, player.height, 30, 30);



  }


  public static void main(String arg[]){
    java.util.Timer vgTimer = new java.util.Timer();  // Create a Timer.
    VGKernel panel = new VGKernel(); // Create an instance of our kernel.

    VGKernel.frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    VGKernel.frame.setSize(VGKernel.screen.width, VGKernel.screen.height);
    VGKernel.frame.setResizable(false);
    VGKernel.frame.setLocation(275, 75);
    VGKernel.frame.setContentPane(panel); 
    VGKernel.frame.setVisible(true);
    VGKernel.frame.setFocusable(true);


    vgTimer.schedule(VGKernel.vgTask, 0, 10);
  }


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        player.x = player.x-5;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        player.x = player.x+5;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        player.y = player.y-5;
    }
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        player.y = player.y+5;
    }

} 




@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}


@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyChar() == 27) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
} 
public void checkCollisions(){
Rectangle r1 = player.getBounds();
Rectangle r2 = Ball.ball[0].getBounds();
Rectangle r3 = Ball.ball[1].getBounds();
Rectangle r4 = Ball.ball[2].getBounds();
Rectangle r5 = Ball.ball[3].getBounds();
Rectangle r6 = Ball.ball[4].getBounds();

if (r1.intersects(r2)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "VGKernel", "Game Over", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    System.exit(0);
}
if (r1.intersects(r3)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "VGKernel", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    System.exit(0);
}
if (r1.intersects(r4)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "VGKernel", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    System.exit(0);
} if (r1.intersects(r5)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "VGKernel", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    System.exit(0);
} if (r1.intersects(r6)) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over", "VGKernel", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 
    System.exit(0);
} 
}
}
```

And a subclass

```
package KernelGame;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Ball extends VGKernel{

    public int x, y, width, height;
    private boolean right, down;

    public Ball(int x, int y, int width, int height, boolean down, boolean right){

    }


    public static void moveBalls(Ball b){
          // Ball should really be its own class with this as a method.
            if (b.right) b.x+=b.width/8; // If right is true, move ball right,
            else b.x-=b.width/8;       // otherwise move left.
            if (b.down)  b.y+=b.height/8; // Same for up/down.
            else b.y-=b.width/8;
            if (b.x > (bounds.width - b.width)) // Detect edges and bounce.
              {b.right = false; b.x = bounds.width -  b.width; }
            if (b.y > (bounds.height - b.height))
              { b.down  = false; b.y = bounds.height - b.height;}
            if (b.x <= 0) { b.right = true; b.x = 0; }
            if (b.y <= 0) { b.down  = true; b.y = 0; }


          }
    public int getX(){ return getX();}
    public int getY(){ return getY();}
    public int getWidth(){ return getWidth();}
    public int getHeight(){ return getHeight();}

}
```

Eclipse shows no errors, but when i run it i get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.awt.AppContext.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.java.swing.SwingUtilities3.getDelegateRepaintManager(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.getDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.repaint(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setFont(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.LookAndFeel.installColorsAndFont(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installDefaults(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at KernelGame.VGKernel.<init>(VGKernel.java:30)
    at KernelGame.Ball.<init>(Ball.java:11)
    at KernelGame.VGKernel.makeBalls(VGKernel.java:43)
    at KernelGame.VGKernel.<init>(VGKernel.java:32)
    at KernelGame.Ball.<init>(Ball.java:11)
    at KernelGame.VGKernel.makeBalls(VGKernel.java:43)
```

I have no idea how to understand all these errors, so help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks:D

Comment: What has your extensive research of `StackOverflowError` told you?

Answer (score 3):

A `Ball`

```
public class Ball extends VGKernel{
```

is a `VGKernel`

```
public class VGKernel extends JPanel implements KeyListener{
```

When you create a `Ball`, you are creating the `VGKernel` part of it as well, ie you're invoking its constructor and initializers as well. That means each `VGKernel` invokes

```
makeBalls();
```

which creates a bunch of `Ball` objects. Those objects are `VGKernel`s as well so their creation also involves invoking

```
makeBalls();
```

which creates more `Ball`s which creates more `Ball`s, ad nauseam.

Basically, you have to fix your whole Object model.

Once you fix these problems, you should also fix those identified by [dognose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23839498/438154). Your getters are also infinitely recursive.

Comment: @tieTYT I've referenced dognose's answer to get the full picture.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how i could rewrite my Object model?

Comment: @user3670545 That seems like quite a task and would not be useful on SO. Just make sure you don't have such recursive behavior. Does a `Ball` need to create balls? What other behavior does not belong to a `Ball`?

Comment: Okay, i made some corrections and it now runs properly. The only problem  is that the balls no longer move correctly. Am i passing the Ball objects to the moveBalls() method properly?

Answer (score 2):

```
public int getX(){ return getX();}
public int getY(){ return getY();}
public int getWidth(){ return getWidth();}
public int getHeight(){ return getHeight();}
```

Your methods are calling the same method again -> infinite loop -> StackOverflow.

You want:

```
public int getX(){ return this.x;}
```

and so on. (And when using getter/setter you could make x,y,widht and height "private".

Comment: That is definitely wrong in their code but doesn't seem related to the error log in question.

Comment: This error is made easier to make because for some reason netbeans insists on suggesting it as the first auto complete (probably because itself is the closest method with the correct return type)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I Assumed Swing is calling the getter for display purpose. (un-posted code) But after TC provided VGKernel, you are obviously right.